# Como asignar una palabra al final de un char?

Tags: c, stm32

tengo este problema, si tengo una variable `char buff[8]` y le paso una cadena de esta forma `snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.4f", volt2);` como puedo hacer para que en el último carácter del char pueda poner un '\n'

Hasta ahorita llevo esto

```
 char buffer[8];
 snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.4f", volt2);
 buffer[7] = '\n';
 CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*) buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

Lo estoy haciendo para una tarjeta stm32, volt2 recibe un valor flotante de un adc, el problema es que cuando reviso la unión serial, no manda el salto de línea y no lo reconoce mi otro lenguaje, buffer debe quedar algo así |1|2|.|9|8|9|\n|

Ahí estoy asignando manualmente el salto en la última posición, pero no funciona no sé qué más hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las cadenas deben estar terminadas en un carácter nulo (0).

[`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) se encarga de escribir uno al final de la cadena. En el caso de 12.989, el buffer se ve así.

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `'1'` | `'2'` | `'.'` | `'9'` | `'8'` | `'9'` | `0` | `'\n'` |

[`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) también se apega a esta convención. Así que como hay un caracter nulo en la posición 6, se envía solo esa parte.

Otra cosa que puede pasar es que si el buffer esté lleno, estés reemplazando el único carácter nulo. Al no encontrar ninguno, `strlen` sigue leyendo hasta encontrar otro o que el programa crashee por leer una dirección de memoria que no debería.

Existe una versión segura de `strlen` que deberías usar para evitar que eso pase, `strnlen_s`.

---

- Preferentemente puedes usar la versión segura de [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat), `strcat_s`.

  ```
  strcat_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "\n", sizeof("\n"));
  ```

  Nota: `sizeof` te devuelve la longitud de un literal de cadena, pero no el de un puntero. Si es el segundo caso, usa `strlen`.
- Sino, primero asegúrate que el buffer tenga espacio suficiente para lo que quieres hacer.

  Luego puedes usar `strcat` para agregar lo que quieras a la cadena.
- Una tercera opción es averiguar dónde está el primer carácter nulo, agregar el caracter en esa posición seguido de un caracter nulo. También habiéndote asegurado de que el buffer tiene suficiente espacio.

  ```
  int posicionNulo = strlen_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  buffer[posicionNulo] = '\n';
  buffer[posicionNulo + 1] = 0;
  ```